# ngModel Angular 5 doesn't work at all and the text box doesn't appear

Tags: angular

```
<input type="text" [(NgModel)]="name">
```

the ngModel doesn't work for some reason
The textbox doesn't appear at all

Comment: Replace `NgModel` with `ngModel`.

Comment: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name"> this not working either... this is what i wanted to post from the first time

Comment: Are there errors in the console? What is `name`?

Comment: name =''; empty string

Comment: are you using template driven form?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: compiler.js:486 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("<input type="text" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="name">
<p>{{name}}</p>

Comment: add name property and check <input type="text" name="Name" [(NgModel)]="name">

Comment: Sounds like you need to import the FormsModule in your module

Comment: How am i doing it?

Comment: See [this page](https://angular.io/guide/forms#revise-appmodulets) of the Angular documentation.

Comment: The problem has been fixes, tnx but when i'm creating a new ng project doesn't have to be imported/created with the project?